# How to handle a User defined Glyph in a user defined Margin in the Visual Studio Editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide

I have an application which uses the Visual Studio shell, NowI extended the editor in my application with a margin in the left side. As Of now I am printing the number of characters in each line in the margin (In a label).

The problem I am facing is that when I scroll down the editor the values I put in the margin is not coming up, I am sure that I put label for each line in the margin.

I want my margin to work like the breakpoint glyph in visual studio ? How to handle the scroll event in the editor or how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a [margin glyph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361745(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of a label.

You can use image functions to overlay the number or combine the number onto an icon. (You could then cache the icons locally). If you follow the article it will handle scrolling for you, so you can let the framework do that.